# Calculating area of blocks in polygon intersect?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap

I need help with calculating the area of blocks in a circular polygon intercept. The circular polygon intercept is 2000m and arable field blocks are present within the intecept. In some of the cases these field blocks are being cut and I would therefore need to know how much of the area of each field block that is inside the polygon. I would like to know this for all the field blocks that are present within the circular polygon intercept.

I have a CSV file that tells me the area of all the arable field blocks present in my shapefile and I have made a circular polygon intercept but I'm unable to make ArcGIS calculate the area of each block inside the polygon, especially the ones being cut.

The intercept was perfomed by creating a buffer and then intercepting the buffer.

Here's a picture of the polygon and the arable field blocks in green and yellow. They are separate colour because of interest in a specific crop - yellow one.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Are you wanting total area, or area of each polygon?  Which polygons are you wanting area of exactly?  How did you perform your intersect?  Please [edit] your question to include details about the process you've followed so far, and what you've tried when attempting to get the area.

Comment: Is it more clear? I'm new to ArcGIS as for last week so I don't have that much experience.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your data is stored (Shapefile, Geodatabase) you may already have an Area field in your attribute table.

Right-click on your layer in ArcMap and select Open Attribute Table.  Look for a field with a name like `SHAPE_AREA`.

If it's not there, you can add a field for area and calculate it from within that open Attribute Table.

1. From the attribute table menu select Add Field
   [image]
2. Give your new field a name, and select the field type.  I would suggest `DOUBLE` as the best type to hold an Area value.  Click OK.
   [image]
3. Right-click on your new field header, and select Calculate Geometry
   [image]
4. In the Calculate Geometry dialog, select your area units, and click OK
   [image]
5. Your layer will now have the area value for each block record in the attribute table
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

You can select the records you are interested in from your feature classes' attribute table (click and drag over records or hold ctrl as you click). Then, right click on the heading containing area attributes and select "statistics." Shown below, the light green area was arable land within my intersection.The two highlighted fields in the attribute table are only those records attributed as "arable" within my the intersect output.

[image]

I believe the answer you are looking for is provided in "SUM". Units are most likely meters if the area field was automatically derived.

You can do this for any selection of records. Or if no records are selected, then all records will be computed in the statistics. Midavalo just provided the solution if your feature class does not already have a field with an area attribute.